# Proof by induction: $f(n) < g(n)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, induction

I have just started learning how to do proof by induction, and no amount of YouTube and stack exchange has led me to work this question out.

Given two functions $f$ and $g$, let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$f(n) = 2n + 1$$

and

$$g(n) = \frac{n^3}{3} - n - 2.$$

We assume that $f(n) < g(n)$ for all $n \ge 4$.

The basis step is straight forward, for $n=4$. It results in $9 < 15.33$, but for the inductive step, I can't figure out how to go about it.

The inductive hypothesis would be: If

$$2n + 1 < \frac{n^3}{3} - n - 2$$

Then

$$2(n+1) + 1 < \frac{(n+1)^3}{3} - (n+1) - 2.$$

Could anyone please give me an idea of how one would prove that? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: expand $(n+1)^3$ and then make use of your induction hypothesis, namely you should use the *inequality* you assume true to just take care of what remains which is easy to prove

Comment: Thanks @Tortar, I added to my question doing that but am still confused.

Comment: Chad, Especially Lime's answer had a rather confusing typo. See if it makes more sense to you now.

Comment: Thanks @TonyK , that correction did help my understanding. I have posted an answer, which I think is correct, please let me know!

Comment: You're almost done. As $2n + 1 < \frac{n^3}{3} - n - 2$ and $0 < n^2 + \frac{2n}{3} + 3.33$, sum of two inequalities leads to what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please let me know if this is correct.

Assuming: $2n + 1 < \frac{1}{3}n^3 - n - 2$

Prove: $2(n+1) + 1 < \frac{1}{3}(n+1)^3 - (n+1) - 2$

RHS:

$2(n+1) + 1 = 2n + 1 + 2$

We know, by the assumption, that this is $< \frac{1}{3}n^3 - n - 2 + 2$, simplified to $< \frac{1}{3}n^3 - n$

We can also see that $\frac{1}{3}n^3 - n < \frac{1}{3}(n+1)^3 - n - 1$

Therefore, we can conclude that

$2n + 1 + 2 < \frac{1}{3}(n+1)^3 - n - 1$

Therefore we prove that

$2(n+1) + 1 < \frac{1}{3}(n+1)^3 - (n+1) - 2$ ​□

Answer (score 0):

The putative inequality can also be re-arranged as

$$ 2n \ + \ 1 \ \ <^{?} \ \ \frac{n^3}{3} \ - \ n \ - \ 2 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 6n + 3 \ \ <^{?} \ \ n^3  - 3n - 6 $$ $$ \Rightarrow \ \ 9 \ \ <^{?} \ \ n^3  - 9n \ \ = \ \ (n - 3)·n·(n+3) \ \ , $$

which makes it easier to see that, for natural numbers, the smallest value of $ \ n \ $ that works is $ \ n  \ = \ 4 \ \ . $  (In fact, this makes me suspicious that the poser of the problem constructed the given functions starting from an expression rather like this.)

The induction would then proceed from taking $ \ 9 \  <  \  (k - 3)·k·(k+3) \ $ to be true to producing the successive statement
$$   9 \ \  <^{?}  \ \ ( \ [k+1] \ - \ 3 \ ) \ · \ [k+1] \ ·\ ( \ [k+1] \ + \ 3 \ ) \ \ . $$
We can then write
$$   9 \ \  <  \ \ (k - 3)·k·(k+3) \ \ < \ \ (k - 3)·k·(k+3) \ · \ \frac{k-2}{k-3} \ · \ \frac{k+1}{k} \ · \ \frac{k+4}{k+3} $$ $$ = \ \  ( k - 2 ) \ · \ (k + 1) \ ·\ (k + 4) \ \ , $$
which is certainly true since each of the multiplicative ratios is greater than $ \ 1 \ \ . $  Hence $ \ f(n) \ < \ g(n) \ \ $ for natural numbers $ \ n \ \ge \ 4 \ \  . $

Answer (score -1):

The key idea is to calculate and compare the differences $f(n+1)-f(n)$ and $g(n+1)-g(n)$. If you know that $f(n)<g(n)$ and also $f(n+1)-f(n)\leq g(n+1)-g(n)$, then it follows that $f(n+1)<g(n+1)$, which is what you want.